# keep divs in view when browser resized vertically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im working on a website that behaves like a desktop where users can drag icons round the screen within a container and then click them to open windows. The issue im having is keeping the icons in view at all times so if a user decreases the browser size vertically, the icons dont disappear off the bottom.

Ive got it working horizontally so if the browser width is reduced the icons will move with the window and stay in view, but I cant get it working vertically if the height of the browser is adjusted (once an icon has been dragged)

See the below example, load the snippet and view it fullscreen, then resize the browser vertically and the text stays in view at all times. But once you move the text then resize the browser it stays where it is rather than moving with the browser.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag-me").draggable({
    containment: "window",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var perc = ui.position.left / ui.helper.parent().width() * 100;
      ui.helper.css('left', perc + '%');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag-me {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 20% ;
    left: 50% ;
    width:50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="drag-me">
  <span>Drag me around!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you bind the graggable object to a div? If yes, mabye making a whole-site parent container for it is an option?

Comment: On the  website im working on the icons are actually in divs and are in a container, ive just used a simplified version here. In the JS above, the following code is how im achieving this for horizontal browser resizing, so Im hoping theres a way to amend this line of code to achieve it for vertical resizing also. `stop: function(e, ui) {
      var perc = ui.position.left / ui.helper.parent().width() * 100;
      ui.helper.css('left', perc + '%');
    }`

Comment: mabye reloading the draggable object to the middle of the div everytime the vievpoing is changed using for example js would work?

Comment: Adding the following code solved this for me -
`var perc = ui.position.top / ui.helper.parent().height() * 100;
      ui.helper.css('top', perc + '%');`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it on **window resize event**

I think that's what you need:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        if($(".drag-me").offset().top + $(".drag-me").height() >= $(window).height()){
          var topPos = $(window).height() - $(".drag-me").height();
          $(".drag-me").css({'top': topPos + 'px'});
        }
    });
  $(".drag-me").draggable({
    containment: "window",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var perc = ui.position.left / ui.helper.parent().width() * 100;
      ui.helper.css({'left': perc + '%'});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it hasnt changed the behaviour of the icons when the browser height is resized though

Comment: it doesn't stay behind when you resize the window if you want the icons to be sorted just add some lines